# Finding the minimum and maximum value within a Metal texture

Tags: ios, multithreading, metal

I have a `MTLTexture` containing 16bit unsigned integers (`MTLPixelFormatR16Uint`). The values range from about 7000 to 20000, with 0 being used as a 'nodata' value, which is why it is skipped in the code below. I'd like to find the minimum and maximum values so I can rescale these values between 0-255. Ultimately I'll be looking to base the minimum and maximum values on a histogram of the data (it has some outliers), but for now I'm stuck on simply extracting the min/max.

*I can read the data from the GPU to CPU and pull the min/max values out but would prefer to perform this task on the GPU.*

**First attempt**

The command encoder is dispatched with 16x16 threads per thread group, the number of thread groups is based on the texture size (eg; width = textureWidth / 16, height = textureHeight / 16).

```
typedef struct {
    atomic_uint min;
    atomic_uint max;
} BandMinMax;

kernel void minMax(texture2d<ushort, access::read> band1 [[texture(0)]],
                   device BandMinMax &out [[buffer(0)]],
                   uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    ushort value = band1.read(gid).r;

    if (value != 0) {
        uint currentMin = atomic_load_explicit(&out.min, memory_order_relaxed);
        uint currentMax = atomic_load_explicit(&out.max, memory_order_relaxed);

        if (value > currentMax) {
            atomic_store_explicit(&out.max, value, memory_order_relaxed);
        }
        if (value < currentMin) {
            atomic_store_explicit(&out.min, value, memory_order_relaxed);
        }
    }
}
```

From this I get a minimum and maximum value, but for the same dataset the min and max will often return different values. Fairly certain this is the min and max from a single thread when there are multiple threads running.

**Second attempt**

Building on the previous attempt, this time I'm storing the individual min/max values from each thread, all 256 (16x16).

```
kernel void minMax(texture2d<ushort, access::read> band1 [[texture(0)]],
                   device BandMinMax *out [[buffer(0)]],
                   uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
                   uint tid [[ thread_index_in_threadgroup ]])
{

    ushort value = band1.read(gid).r;

    if (value != 0) {
        uint currentMin = atomic_load_explicit(&out[tid].min, memory_order_relaxed);
        uint currentMax = atomic_load_explicit(&out[tid].max, memory_order_relaxed);

        if (value > currentMax) {
            atomic_store_explicit(&out[tid].max, value, memory_order_relaxed);
        }
        if (value < currentMin) {
            atomic_store_explicit(&out[tid].min, value, memory_order_relaxed);
        }
    }
}
```

This returns an array containing 256 sets of min/max values. From these I guess I could find the lowest of the minimum values, but this seems like a poor approach. Would appreciate a pointer in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Metal Shading Language has atomic compare-and-swap functions you can use to compare the existing value at a memory location with a value, and replace the value at that location if they don't compare equal. With these, you can create a set of atomic compare-and-replace-if-[greater|less]-than operations:

```
static void atomic_uint_exchange_if_less_than(volatile device atomic_uint *current, uint candidate)
{
    uint val;
    do {
        val = *((device uint *)current);
    } while ((candidate < val || val == 0) && !atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(current,
                                                                                     &val,
                                                                                     candidate,
                                                                                     memory_order_relaxed,
                                                                                     memory_order_relaxed));
}

static void atomic_uint_exchange_if_greater_than(volatile device atomic_uint *current, uint candidate)
{
    uint val;
    do {
        val = *((device uint *)current);
    } while (candidate > val && !atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(current,
                                                                       &val,
                                                                       candidate,
                                                                       memory_order_relaxed,
                                                                       memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

To apply these, you might create a buffer that contains one interleaved min, max pair per threadgroup. Then, in the kernel function, read from the texture and conditionally write the min and max values:

```
kernel void min_max_per_threadgroup(texture2d<ushort, access::read> texture [[texture(0)]],
                                    device uint *mapBuffer [[buffer(0)]],
                                    uint2 tpig [[thread_position_in_grid]],
                                    uint2 tgpig [[threadgroup_position_in_grid]],
                                    uint2 tgpg [[threadgroups_per_grid]])
{
    ushort val = texture.read(tpig).r;

    device atomic_uint *atomicBuffer = (device atomic_uint *)mapBuffer;

    atomic_uint_exchange_if_less_than(atomicBuffer + ((tgpig[1] * tgpg[0] + tgpig[0]) * 2),
                                      val);

    atomic_uint_exchange_if_greater_than(atomicBuffer + ((tgpig[1] * tgpg[0] + tgpig[0]) * 2) + 1,
                                         val);
}
```

Finally, run a separate kernel to reduce over this buffer and collect the final min, max values across the entire texture:

```
kernel void min_max_reduce(constant uint *mapBuffer [[buffer(0)]],
                           device uint *reduceBuffer [[buffer(1)]],
                           uint2 tpig [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    uint minv = mapBuffer[tpig[0] * 2];
    uint maxv = mapBuffer[tpig[0] * 2 + 1];

    device atomic_uint *atomicBuffer = (device atomic_uint *)reduceBuffer;

    atomic_uint_exchange_if_less_than(atomicBuffer, minv);

    atomic_uint_exchange_if_greater_than(atomicBuffer + 1, maxv);
}
```

Of course, you can only reduce over the total allowed thread execution width of the device (~256), so you may need to do the reduction in multiple passes, with each one reducing the size of the data to be operated on by a factor of the maximum thread execution width.

*Disclaimer*: This may not be the best technique, but it does appear to be correct in my limited testing of an OS X implementation. It was marginally faster than a naive CPU implementation on a 256x256 texture on Intel Iris Pro, but substantially slower on an Nvidia GT 750M (because of dispatch overhead).

Comment: Thanks @warrenm, seems to be working. I have a question about the offset for the atomic buffer; eg `atomicBuffer + ((tgpig[1] * tpt[0] + tgpig[0]) * 2)`. My understanding is that atomic operations apply per threadgroup (please correct any of these assumptions if wrong BTW)? I use 16x16 threads by thread group passed into the kernel via the `threads_per_threadgroup` annotation to the `tpt` variable. I'm not sure this is the width of my thread group grid? eg; texture size is 192x160, with threadgroup grid 12x10, and the offset calc `atomicBuffer + ((tgpig[1] * 12 + tgpig[0]) * 2)`?

Comment: Please excuse the hardcoded 12 in that last line. I think what I'm trying to say is replacing `threads_per_threadgroup` with `threadgroups_per_grid` in the min_max_per_threadgroup kernel fixes it?

Comment: @lock Yep, you're absolutely correct. I got lucky in my implementation because `threads_per_threadgroup` happened to be equal to `threadgroups_per_grid`. Corrected above.

Comment: TBH, this has probably helped my understanding more than if it was right from the start. Thanks again.

Comment: Warrenm, I am curious, how are you doing to switch Metal code execution from Iris to Nvidia ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It works well on me.

```
kernel void grayscale_texture_minmax(texture2d<half, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
                             device atomic_uint *min_max [[buffer(0)]],
                             uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if ((gid.x >= inTexture.get_width()) || (gid.y >= inTexture.get_height())) {
        return;
    }
    // true color to gray scaled
    const half4 inColor = inTexture.read(gid);
    const half clr = inColor.r;
    const uint intColor = uint(clamp(clr, 0.h, 1.h)*255.h);
    
    atomic_fetch_min_explicit(&min_max[0], intColor, memory_order_relaxed);
    atomic_fetch_max_explicit(&min_max[1], intColor, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```